# How to display data on table view on search in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, search, sqlite

I have a project where there is a table view and the textfield and the button and i have a sqlite database within the project. In my database i have fields like name, city, state,zip, latitude and longitude. Currently i am displaying the name of the latitude and longitude, when the user gives 100 in the textfield,i.e user can give any meters 100 or 200, depending on meters it is displaying the name of the corresponding latitude and longitude depending on the current latitude and longitude. 
To achieve this i am using the following code,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [resultArray count];

}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}

 - (void) readDataFromDatabase{

sqlite3 *database;
info = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if (sqlite3_open([[self getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){

    const char *sqlStatement = "select * from tourism";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"SQLITE_OK");
        while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            pID = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);
            pName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSLog(@"%@",pName);
            pAdd = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            NSLog(@"%@",pAdd);
            pCity = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
            NSLog(@"%@",pCity);
            pState = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
            NSLog(@"%@",pState);
            pZip = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
            NSLog(@"%@",pZip);
            pWebsite = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 6)];
            NSLog(@"%@",pWebsite);
            pCategory = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 7)];
            NSLog(@"%@",pCategory);
            pLat = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 8)];
            NSLog(@"%@",pLat);
            pLong = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 9)];
            NSLog(@"%@",pLong);
            pGeolocation = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 10)];
            NSLog(@"%@",pGeolocation);
            GreenValleyInfo *temp = [[GreenValleyInfo alloc]initWithUniqueId:(int)pID name:(NSString *)pName address:(NSString *)pAdd city:(NSString *)pCity state:(NSString *)pState zip:(NSString *)pZip website:(NSString *)pWebsite category:(NSString*)pCategory latitude:(NSString *)pLat longitude:(NSString *)pLong geolocation:(NSString *)pGeolocation];
            [info addObject:temp];
            [temp release];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
 }
```

### startTest

```
    - (void)startTest
   {

      [resultArray removeAllObjects];
     for(int j=0;j<[info count];j++){

          GreenValleyInfo *arr = [info objectAtIndex:j];
         RADIUS = [Proxy.text intValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[COORDS_COUNT] = {
          CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([arr.latitude floatValue], [arr.longitude floatValue]),
   };

CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat floatValue], [longt floatValue]); 
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:center radius:RADIUS identifier:@"Locations"];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = coords[0];

    if ([region containsCoordinate:coord])
    {
        NSLog(@"location %f, %f,%@ is within %i meters of coord %f, %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude,arr.name, RADIUS, center.latitude, center.longitude);
        [resultArray addObject:arr.name];

    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"location %f, %f,%@ is not within %i meters of coord %f, %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude,arr.name, RADIUS, center.latitude, center.longitude);    
    }
   }
 }
```

But now I need to change the search method, i.e, instead of giving the meters now I need to give city or zip in the textfield and it has to display the corresponding name in the table view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doenload this code https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the code in the startTest method. You are getting an object from info array to arr array. Now after this you need to put a check with the value of search field name / zipcode inserted with the value of *arr object.

For e.g.

```
if ([arr.name isEqualTo searchField.text] || [arr.zip isEqualTo searchField.text]) 
         {
// stuff to add object to the array which is displayed in the tableview.
}
```

And delete the code return for the co-ordinate stuff or you can comment for future use if it is required.

Hope this help you.

Comment: i tried with what you told, but it is giving error - use of undeclared identifier 'arr' near the if statement.

Comment: You should write that code below this line GreenValleyInfo *arr = [info objectAtIndex:j];

Comment: I added and inside the if-loop i added the following line [resultArray addObject:arr.name]; and I kept the brealpoint to the loop, it is not entering to the loop only.

Comment: Where you are capturing the search value. Some code related to the search instance.

Comment: If it is not entering in the for loop or the if loop.

Comment: It is not entering the if loop.

Comment: Print all the arr values using nslog before if loop. Also print the search field value as well.